# Apache Cgi-bin in C programming language

Tags: c, localhost, cgi, cgi-bin

hello I would like to deploy this git-hub repository in to localhost webserver. I used apache 2.2 and able to deploy it in localhost webserver.

https://github.com/drahosj/NCDC15-WWW

but unable to execute files in CGi-bin folder. Please help me, my project is due in next week. The files in CGI-bin are written in C programming language.

here is the readme for above repository.
https://github.com/apples723/NCDC15-Website-Read-Me

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: try `chmod` and `chown` commands on the binary. The executable might not be executable by your apache server user. You can `ls -l` in the cgi-bin directory to see what the permissions and file owners are.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention. I am using windows. I don't think there is anything wrong with the file permissions. I think its with apache configuration to let it able to execute files in cgi-bin.

Comment: And i am not supposed to alter any files in this project. I need to deploy it to local host and perform penetration testing on this web application